# how do i change the shm_open path?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, shared-memory

i am currently developing an application on ubunto and calling shm_open, currently the default path is within /var/run/shm. however i need to change this to /tmp. simply trying the following does not work:

fd = shm_open( "/tmp/test", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0777 );

can anyone please advise?

Comment: What is the error code returned by querying `errno`?

Comment: if you mean fd  - it returns 3

Comment: Okay, so that's a valid file-descriptor ... why are you saying it's not working?

Comment: sorry my mistake, when i get rid of /tmp it returns 3. however when executing the above -1 is returned

Comment: Okay, so what happens when you call `perror(NULL);` after `shm_open` returns `-1`?

Comment: i get the following message: No such file or directory

Comment: The problem is there is no directory like `/dev/shm/tmp/` ... so you can't create a file called `/dev/shm/tmp/test` since the `tmp` directory doesn't exist.  @Mihai answer is correct if you must use `/tmp`, otherwise you can simply use `test`, and that will create `/dev/shm/test`.

Comment: Here is another link you can try: http://fixunix.com/sgi/112129-linux-shm_open-bad-file-descriptor-sgi-runs-well.html

Comment: well i wish to have persistent files after reset so ideally i need them within /tmp not within /dev/tmp, is there a way around this?

Comment: That's not the way shared memory objects work ... on Linux they are by default created inside of `/dev/shm`, and if you want them somewhere else, you have to mount a `tmpfs` file-system in that desired directory.

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong, i need to do a mount | grep shm within the /tmp directory?

Comment: Yeah, that part is a little confusing, see @Hristo answer ... if you wanted to create the `tmpfs` mount at `/tmp`, you would actually do that within `fstab`

Comment: any articles on this to help me on that way? This is all new to me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the man page of `shm_open(3)`:

> `name` specifies the shared memory object to be created or opened.  For portable use, a shared memory object should be identified by a name of the form `/somename`; that  is,  a  null-terminated  string of up to `NAME_MAX` (i.e., 255) characters consisting of an initial slash, followed by one or more characters, *none of which are slashes*.

The `name` parameter of `shm_open(3)` is an object name, not a file path! It just happens that GLIBC places all shared memory objects in `/dev/shm` or `/var/run/shm` by prepending the path to the object name and calling `open()` on the resulting name. If you specify `/tmp/test` as the shared object name then Linux would try to open or create `/var/run/shm/tmp/test`. Open with `O_CREAT` creates new files but *does not create new directories*.

Your test will work if your first create the directory `/var/run/shm/tmp` before the call to `shm_open("/tmp/test", ...)`. Remember to remove it once you have finished working with the shared memory object. And also note that using object name with two slashes inside might not be portable to other Unix systems.

Comment: Where can I set the destination path  eg: `/dev/shm`?

Comment: @DDS you can't. On Linux, it searches for a `tmpfs` mount which is usually mounted under `/dev/shm` or `/var/run/shm`.

Comment: in my case either /var/volatile and /run are tempfs
and my layout is like this: /tmp -> /var/tmp -> /var/volatile/tmp

Answer (score 2):

You need to mount a `tmpfs` filesystem in `/tmp` for this:

```
mihai@keldon:~$ mount | grep shm
shm on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
```

Otherwise, it is not possible.

Comment: i tried mount | grep shm but got the following none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)

Comment: My bad, the above only showed the type of the filesystem mounted there. You need to mount it using `mount`.