# Can Boost message queue file be redirected to user specified location

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

How can i redirect creation of Boost message queue file to user specified directory.
        I am using ubuntu. 
        Currently it gets created on /dev/shm location. 
        File is same as message queue name. 
        I tried defining macro BOOST_INTERPROCESS_SHARED_DIR_FUNC and implemented function 
            get_shared_dir. But it is not working.
       Below is my code :
       File : message_queue_dir_path.h

```
    #include <string>
    namespace boost {
        namespace interprocess {
            namespace ipcdetail {
                void get_shared_dir(std::&shared_dir){
                    shared_dir = "/home/username/message_queue_dir";
                }
           }
       }
    }
```

And define macro in BOOST_INTERPROCESS_SHARED_DIR_FUNC in compilation.
        But still it is not creating the file at give location. It goes to /dev/shm

Answer (score 2):

I debugged similar situation on CentOS 7 and my findings are:
on Linux it is not possible to change shared_dir using get_shared_dir. It will be in /dev/shm (or wherever is your tmpfs mounted).

Reason for that is on Linux boost message_queue is using "shm_open" internally. And shm_open allows only for "object name", not a file path.

On Windows your solution works as a charm.

If you would like to look yourself at the code you can found it in boost\interprocess\shared_memory_object.hpp, function shared_memory_object::priv_open_or_create.

Related issue: [how do i change the shm_open path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102599/how-do-i-change-the-shm-open-path)